# Undefined value when accessing environment variables with dynamic key in Next.js13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I’m using Next.js 13. I need to get data from an .env file using a dynamic key. I get the page type in a client component, for example - “HOME”. I need to extract data from the .env file. I can do this by directly referring to the variable like this: `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_HOME` and it works. But when I try to get data using a dynamic key, I get undefined.
Here is my code:

```
const YandexMetrika: React.FC<YandexMetrikaProps> = ({ page }) => {
  const [page_, setPage] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(page)
  }, [page])

  if (!page_) return null

  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_HOME) // successful get data from .env
  console.log(process.env[`NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_${page_}`])// undefined. page_ is HOME here


  return()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the environment variable name as a whole, you cannot dynamically create the environment variable name.
To use based on your variable, you can do the following:

```html
switch (page_) {
     case 'HOME':
         console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_HOME);
         break;
     case 'BLOG':
         console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_BLOG);
         break;

     default:
         console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_METRIKA_PROFILE)
         break;
}
```